# How to replace certain part of dynamic string

Tags: asp.net, string, vb.net, replace

I want to replace a certain part of dynamic string in vb.net. I will try to explain it in this example:

I have a STRING like this:
&12=1005&14=96&230=28&1116=0074005&1271=45&1272%**3d001002003**%2612%1276=1

and I want this part **3d001002003** to be changed with some other text that I have entered in a Textbox (or any other element).

Problem is that this STRING is sometimes different in character size:

1. &12=1005&14=96&230=28&1116=0074005&1271=45&1272%**3d001002003**%2612%1276=1
2. &12=15&14=96&230=28&1116=0075&1271=45&1272%**3d021022023**%26276=1... and so on.

Only constant thing in this STRING is that part which needs to be changed always starts with **3d** and always has **11 characters**. So, something what I'm looking for is to find the part of string that starts with **3d** and contains **11 characters** and then replace it with some other content from Textbox.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Get the index of `%3d` and then do `Replace` with `index+11` Or other way is you can write regex to match the string and then replace it with matched value.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could post an example for me, because I'm not so familiar with coding in general. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using below regex

```
^3d(?!.*  )(?=.*[\w-])[\w -]{11}$
```

(starting with 3d with following total 11 characters)

OR

```
^%3d[0-9]{9}%
```

(starting with **%3d** with following total 9 numeric(assuming only numeric in-between) ending with **%**   = total 11)

in vb.net

example:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("&12=15&14=96&230=28&1116=0075&1271=45&1272%3d021022023%26276=1", "%3d[0-9]{9}%", "%R%", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
```